# scroll to next item in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

With an example like the below using `angular.element`, how could I scroll to the next item in an ng-repeat on every click?

This is what I have so far, I just don't know what to do next:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

   $scope.items = [{
      name: "apple"
   }, {
      name: "pear"
   }, {
      name: "Avacado"
   }, {
      name: "Banana"
   }];

   $scope.go = function ($event) {
      console.log(angular.element($event.currentTarget).parent().next());
   };

}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="box" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
         <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
        <button ng-click="go($event)">go to next box</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0bwcLfv4/2/

jQuery is included on the site already, so I certainly want animation for every scroll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now sure how fancy your trying to get. You can do something basic like  HTML anchor tags.

```
<a name="section1">Section 1</a>
```

alongside

```
<a href="#section1">Go to section 1</a>
```

Comment: Adding to this, you could simply number the sections (1,2,3) and use a counter binded to the generic click event: 

    $(document).click(function(){ counter++; } );

Answer (score 3):

You can start with a custom directive on each anchor (I use anchor in this example since it is more semantically correct for navigation purposes) that will listen for click events and scroll the view accordingly. You feed that directive with the index of next element, so it knows where to scroll to.

```
<div scroll-box>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items ...">
        ...
        <a scroll-to-next="{{ ($index + 1) % items.length }}">...</a>
        <!-- make the last element point to the first one -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The `scroll-box` is a wrapper directive to which the `scroll-to-next` directive will log the element on which it resides. This is to avoid making queries for elements, it's more "the angular way" of doing things.
Instead of doing query the `scroll-to-next` directive will ask the wrapper for the next element using the given index.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iotEaOHh34FIRFoX6kFy?p=preview) with working implementation.

Answer (score 2):

For smooth scrolling, you can use **animate** and **offset** functions by **jQuery**.

**Here's the [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/0bwcLfv4/9/).**

**E.g.**


**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <div class="box" id="box{{$index}}" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
            <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
            <button ng-click="go('#box' + ($index + 1))">go to next box</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added `id="box{{$index}}"` to assign the **targetId**.

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.items = [{
        name: "apple"
    }, {
        name: "pear"
    }, {
        name: "Avacado"
    }, {
        name: "Banana"
    }];

    $scope.go = function(targetId){
        var destination = $(targetId).offset().top;
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: destination}, 300);
    };

}]);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="box" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" id="question{{item.id}}">
         <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
        <button ng-click="go(item.id + 1)">go to next box</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.go = function (aid) {

  $timeout(function() {
     var idheight = $(window).height() + $('#question'+aid).position().top-100;
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: idheight}, 1000);
  }, 500);

 };
```